How do I solve the problem where the "-" character becomes "/" when I print on a TSC label printer?
I have a TSC printer, model TX200, with a Symbol barcode scanner connected to it via USB. The printer is not connected to any computer or network. It is used to print a serial number and a corresponding barcode by scanning another barcode with the scanner. The scanned barcode contains a serial number in the format 530-2024-111111. While the serial number can vary, the "-" characters are always present.
The issue I'm facing is that when I scan a barcode with a serial number like 530-2024-111111, the printer outputs 530/2024/111111. I need to retain the "-" characters in the serial number so that the printout shows 530-2024-111111.
I'm using the following script, which is sent to the printer:
SPEED 5.0
DENSITY 10
SET PEEL OFF
REFERENCE 0,0
OFFSET 0.00 mm
SET CUTTER OFF
CLS
CODEPAGE 1252
COUNTRY 046
DIRECTION 1,0
:START
INPUT "NAMN :",VAR1$
BARCODE 0,0,"128",35,1,0,1,2,VAR1$
PRINT 1,1
GOTO START
EOP
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Checked the barcode scanner by connecting it to a computer and scanning into Notepad. The serial number is read correctly, including the "-" characters.
Performed a factory reset on the printer.
Switched to another TSC printer of the same model.
Changed the barcode type to Code 39.
Tried different CODEPAGE values.

Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I continue to get "/" instead of "-" in the printed output.
I would appreciate any further suggestions on how to resolve this issue.
